# Function related libraries, or single service layer?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, n-tier-architecture

My team and I are looking for evidence to support either a multi library approach for like functionality, or condensing all of this functionality within a single service layer. It's important to note that this is going to be sitting behind a web api and either approach is valid, but we need to decide which holds more benefit. To illustrate the layer(s) we are looking at the following is what we'll have:

```
Solution
    WebAPI
    Services ---- This is what we're looking at
    DataAccess
```

Bear in mind that if we did use the multi library approach we would still have a Services project, but it would be much thinner and have more specific functionality. We are not planning to independently deploy these libraries, but have everything needing to reference them either in the same solution, or access them via the web api.

What the rest of us would propose is something like the following:

```
Solution
    WebAPI
    Services
    Services.Geography        ---
    Services.Membership       --- This is the alternative approach
    Services.ProductDelivery  ---
    etc...
```

The benefits we see in the first option is having all of this code organized within a single library which allows for easier extraction of duplicate code, potentially unit testing, and perhaps some relief from the build process.

The benefits of option two are having a clear delineation in functionality between projects, having isolated code which is potentially portable should the need arise, and generally being able to independently work on and configure different facets of the application.

The drawbacks we see in option one are that the Service layer now becomes responsible for each facet of the application, which bloats that library and in my opinion sort of violates Single Responsibility. We realize that rule is not as applicable to libraries so much as it is methods and classes, but it still seems like there are other benefits to be had by separating functionality. There's also the potential to mistakenly place code somewhere it doesn't belong, or use classes available to the entire project where they may not apply.

The drawbacks in option two are an obvious increase in overhead on project builds, working in configs (even though this may be desirable) and potentially cluttering the solution with more projects than necessary. I think we'd plan to consolidate like functionality into single projects (ie, we might build multiple implementations of ProductDelivery within that project to be able to switch between them or use different ones for different reasons).

We realize all of our business rules can be accomplished with either approach, we just have reached an impasse in deciding which approach is better practice.

So the question is, which of these two approaches is better practice?

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 things that can make me think to chose the first option:

- Your services use only one data layer library.
- Your services are really short (something like implementing just the CRUD)

*Split in libraries, a class that count few lines in an entire library, can be awkward. Unless, you know it will grow a lot after (in several classes, of course).*

If not, I would say the option 2, is better because:

- it's easier to replace a part of the service like that. Change the library that you want, and it's done.
- it should be more abstracted, if you want to avoid strong coupling between each library
- it should be easier to test a specific part of it.
- it should be more configurable, and you can configure all of them in the project that references all of them (Even, if one or several libraries doesn't change a lot of things).
- it should be less like a god library
- it might be more exportable for some others projects, depending on how specialized your libraries are.

And I disagree, for these points:

> a single library which allows for easier extraction of duplicate code

If you are careful, your duplicate code, can be extracted in a parent library, common to all the others. So all your duplicate code, should be automatically extracted (Except, if there is a lack of communication or people prefer to copy/paste code. But, one library would not change that. It might even be harder to find where the code already exists).

> potentially unit testing

Why several libraries have to be more difficult to test ?
If you have several libraries, you will have to make them more abstracted, to allow the change. And then, your testing should be easy.

> and perhaps some relief from the build process.

Why ? If all your libraries are well named, where would be your problems ?
Deploying a dll or several dlls, shouldn't be that hard.
If it's about the configuration, one library or more, you will still have the same configuration to make, not necessarily more (but probably a bit more).

---

I also disagree for the single responsability doesn't apply to libraries. It is.
Each library, should be responsible for one business, not all of them. If you finish with a set of libraries, it can become a framework. Even, for a framework, you will finish to have a single responsability but much more general, than the responsibility of methods, classes, libraries, etc...

---

*But you might want an opinion from a more advanced architect/developer than me.*

*If someone disagree with me, don't hesitate to comment my answer. I would be happy to learn from your knowledge*

Comment: The current plan is to have a single data layer. Many of our potential other libraries would be third party api wrappers that don't necessarily need to interact with the database. Those that do could potentially have their own data layer which may or may not interact with the same database or an independent database. I think doing that makes them self contained and able to exist without the rest of the solution. Still not totally sure if this is the approach we want to take yet though.

Comment: Do you use dependency injection ?

Comment: Yes we do, and StructureMap as our IoC dependency resolver

Answer (score 1):

With the comments from my first answer in mind.

> The current plan is to have a single data layer. Many of our potential
>   other libraries would be third party api wrappers that don't
>   necessarily need to interact with the database. Those that do could
>   potentially have their own data layer which may or may not interact
>   with the same database or an independent database. I think doing that
>   makes them self contained and able to exist without the rest of the
>   solution. Still not totally sure if this is the approach we want to
>   take yet though.

Dependency injection ?

> StructureMap as our IoC dependency resolver

---

You will end up with several libraries, unless, all your libraries you use, have to use themselves together.

You will either have your services becoming kind of proxies for the third party libraries, or your services will use proxies for the third party libraries.

But anyway, the proxy parts, should not be together in same library. It would be harder to change the third party library, if you do that.

If you chose the solution where your services use proxies for the third party libraries. You can inject these proxies into your services easily, thanks to the dependency injection.
If you change of third party library, change the proxy implementation and change the injection, and it's done.

But, if you chose to make your services the proxies. It's almost the same, but you have one layer less. And your service implementations have to be exported in different libraries. You will also have to be more careful when changing your service, because you will endup breaking things elsewhere in your app.
For that last point, having a proxy layer used by your services, sounds better to me, at the moment.

---

*I'm still thinking. It will have more edits to come I imagine*

Comment: So I guess the dilemma is some of us want to create third party libraries, the rest want to roll all functionality into the service layer organized into different namespaces, so there essentially is no real proxy anymore. I'm personally on the side of use libraries, for reasons discussed, and that there's more potential for problems to arise if everything exists within a single service/business layer with no proxy between the api and the business layer.

Comment: What are the arguments of those who think one library would be better ? The several namespaces is not a valid point, since you can have these namespaces with different libraries, but with less "coupling" between them.

Comment: That extensibility won't be an issue, and that having too many libraries will create unnecessary or undue overhead in maintenance and build process. That having too many libraries also creates a risk for developers to mistakenly create references between projects that they shouldn't. Testing won't be any harder, and it will be easier to determine which other libraries are using code within one library, as opposed to having several which makes determining dependencies more difficult.

Comment: We do have other projects/solutions that we have deployed in the past using an less than ideal build and deployment process which use some of these libraries, and we are trying to condense many of these into a single solution so we don't have the problem of not knowing which consumers we're affecting until after a change has been deployed. I think that is a different problem though and not one that really has any bearing on the decision we're trying to make. We'll still have those other projects out there regardless of having a single library or many business logic libraries.

Comment: I see. I agree about having too many references can a be problem. But I still think it can support easier the evolution, than a single one. But finally the question is, how many services depend on the same third  party libraries ? Because, in this case, you can regroup all the services using the same third party together, and split the others in another one. Like that, if you change one third party, you change only the services (in the same library) that use it. It's kinda an hybrid solution, between a single library and several.

Comment: The idea is that everything we use would eventually call to the services they need via the api. So we would have the api as the presentation layer, a service layer to expose our business logic, and then either roll all business logic into the service layer or a single business logic library, OR separate business logic into libraries that encapsulate similar functionality. For example, I think we should create a library for travel related third party services. Within that, there would be the logic for each service as it pertains to travel.

Comment: The example in the above comment is one such possibility. Another possibility might be we make a Hotels library, which may have wrappers for multiple different hotel providers but they would all adhere to something like an `IHotels` interface so as to unify their implementation. The consumer could configure which one they'd like to use. The first example is the more likely of the two, but we do have at least 1 use case for this example as well.